# How to do arithmetic in Python with SQLite database selections

Tags: python, list, sqlite, math, concatenation

I'm trying to add (not concatenate) a single SQLite selection from my database, but it returns the value as a list and tries to concatenate it.
I'm looking at the line "total = users + values."
I'm developing a web flask app that manages mock stock portfolio transactions. Please help!
The 'users' table's 'cash' column is NUMERIC and the 'portfolio' table's 'shares' and 'price' column are INTEGER and NUMERIC

```
users = db.execute("SELECT cash FROM users WHERE id = :id", id=session["user_id"])
portfolio = db.execute("SELECT * FROM portfolio WHERE id = :id", id=session["user_id"])

values = 0
total = users
if portfolio:
    for each in portfolio:
        values= values + (each.shares * each.price)
        total = users + values

#value = usd( total )
value = users
return render_template("index.html", stock=portfolio, user=users, value=value)
```

Comment: Your `users ` variable is `sqlite3.Cursor` object, so is `total`. You are trying to add up 'sqlite3.Cursor' and 'float', I don't think `total = users + values` is even runnable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As luochenhuan noted in the comments, `sqlite3.execute` returns a `sqlite3.Cursor` object, so your `user` and `portfolio` variables are actually cursors, not iterable collections of values. In order to make these iterable, you need to call the `.fetchall()` method on these in order to get back a list of results.

Once you do this, each result in these lists will be a tuple representing the row in your SQLite database, not properties with named attributes. So, to get the values you're interested in, you'll either have to access them by index, or, load them into a `Collections.namedtuple` instance to access them by a named attribute.

Comment: thank you for clarifying my mistake. the cursor object returns a JSON-esque object inside brackets, would there be an easy way to reference values from this 'users' table:    [{'id': 1, 'username': 'truth', 'hash': 'PassW0rd'}]